Difference between running a userform in Visual Basic Editor (F5) and opening it with Show?
I have a userform (form_Updaterow), putting together some scripts to show additional info in a label when a textbox is clicked on.
It works when I F5-run the userform. When I open the form using .Show (either from another form or from a macro), the script does not work. Could running and showing make something different?
This is what I am (in theory) doing:
1.In the form's (form_Updaterow) I define a new collection for TextBoxes when initialising the form. (I added a MsgBox to confirm it runs this code.)
Dim tbCollection As Collection
Dim cbCollection As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
MsgBox ("UserForm initialized")
    Sheets("DES").Activate
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    
    Dim obj_tb As clsTextBox
    Set tbCollection = New Collection
        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
                Set obj_tb = New clsTextBox
                Set obj_tb.Control = ctrl
                tbCollection.Add obj_tb
            End If
        Next ctrl
    Set obj_tb = Nothing
End Sub

2.In a class module (clsTextBox):
Private WithEvents MyTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Set Control(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
'MsgBox ("TextBox property set")
    Set MyTextBox = tb
End Property

Private Sub MyTextBox_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
'MsgBox ("Call the provider")
    Call TheInfoProvider
End Sub

3.In a module (mod_Infos) I loop through my textboxes and identify the one that has been clicked on. (Because some of the textboxes are in frames, I had to add the activename() function. I couldn't make it work otherwise). I then use the textbox's name ('txt_VARNAME') to identify the guidance text in a table (DatDic_DES).
Public Sub TheInfoProvider()
'MsgBox ("I'm the Info Provider")
For Each c In form_Updaterow.Controls

    If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
        MsgBox activename
        If c.Name = activename() Then
        
            varname = Split(c.Name, "_", 2)(1)
            
            Set DatDic = Worksheets("Data Dictionary").ListObjects("DatDic_DES")
            varnames = DatDic.ListColumns("Variable Name").Range
            tabrow = Application.Match(varname, varnames, 0)
            
            form_Updaterow.fr_varname.Visible = True
            form_Updaterow.lbl_varname.Caption = varname
            
            guidance = DatDic.ListColumns("Guidance").Range.Cells(tabrow)
            form_Updaterow.lbl_guidance.Caption = guidance
        End If
        
    End If
Next c
End Sub

Public Function activename() As String 'MSForms.Control
    Set ReallyActiveControl = form_Updaterow.ActiveControl
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ReallyActiveControl = ReallyActiveControl.ActiveControl
    activename = ReallyActiveControl.Name
End Function

When I run the form (form_Updaterow) using F5 the code works: I get my "UserForm initialized" message and then a pop-up with the name of the clicked-upon text box (multiple times, once for each textbox in my form). The result is that the label (lbl_guidance) now has changed to the guidance text for that textbox.
However, when I load the form using .Show, for example using the macro below (also when I load from another form): Before showing the form, I get my "UserForm initialized" message (so far, so good). Then, when I click on a textbox I get the same message again, and then multiple empty message boxes.
Public Sub Main()
    Dim frm As New form_Updaterow
    frm.Show vbModel
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub

The problem seems to be in identifying the ActiveControl.
What makes trouble-shooting so challenging is that the behaviour is different when I F5-run the form and when I .Show the form using a macro (or button in another userform). I think it would help to understand the fundamental difference between one way and another of loading my form.
I am using Excel on Office 365, ,Version 2408 (Build 17928.20156 Click-to-Run) and VBA 7.1.1143

Difference I see is that in your class, you are using the Default Instance of your form. When you run the Form with F5, you are also using the Default Instance. However, your code in Main creates an own instance of the the form.

Why not pass the text box from MyTextBox_MouseDown into TheInfoProvider ?

TheInfoProvider MyTextBox (use of Call is generally deprecated I think)

@TimWilliams Because I am trying to make a system that applies to all textboxes so that in the future collaborators can adapt the form just adding text boxes and without having to get into the code.

@FunThomas I have the same problem when I call the form using
With New form_Updaterow
.Show
End With
which I think addresses what you were suggesting?

There's nothing textbox-specific about my suggested change: you already have a reference to the textbox in your event-handling class instance, and you pass that directly to TheInfoProvider, instead of having TheInfoProvider try to figure it out...

@Tim Williams Sorry, I think I understood now. I modified the  replaced Call TheInfoProvider by TheInfoProvider MyTextBox (and modified the function to accept an argument) and that now works like a charm! TheInfoProvider does not need to loop through all fields, now. Hooray!
However, even though in theory all works, the guidance label is not being updated, even though MsgBox form_Updaterow.lbl_guidance.Caption does show the new value. This seems like a different problem now... I'll add a response below with the updated code.

Seems like you need a way to get a reference to the running instance of form_Updaterow - you should be able to get that from the .Parent  property of the passed textbox?

@TimWilliams Indeed that solved it, too (even though the value was the same as I had written). At least for the fields in the main form. Still has issues with fields in frames, but I think I can figure that one out (worst case I just take them out of frame)

Thanks to @TimWilliams for providing the solution for the initial problem. Instead of calling TheInfoProvider and having it find the selected TextBox using a loop, passing it the TextBox directly solved that issue. Another problem came up when updating the guidance label, though, which got solved after @TimWilliams suggested using .Parent (with a little tweak in case of textboxes that were in a frame).
Here is the new, fully working code:
In the clsTextBox class module
Private Sub MyTextBox_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    TheInfoProvider MyTextBox
End Sub

In the mod_Infos module (I commented out the old code to show the difference)
Public Sub TheInfoProvider(c)
'MsgBox ("I'm the Info Provider")
'    For Each c In form_Updaterow.Controls
'
'        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
'            MsgBox cargo.Name
'            If c.Name = cargo.Name Then
        Dim ancestry As Object
        Set ancestry = c.Parent
        If c.Parent.Name <> "form_Updaterow" Then
            Set ancestry = c.Parent.Parent
        End If
        varname = Split(c.Name, "_", 2)(1)
        Set DatDic = Worksheets("Data Dictionary").ListObjects("DatDic_DES")
        varnames = DatDic.ListColumns("Variable Name").Range
        tabrow = Application.Match(varname, varnames, 0)
        
        ancestry.fr_varname.Visible = True
        ancestry.lbl_varname.Caption = varname
        
        guidance = DatDic.ListColumns("Guidance").Range.Cells(tabrow)
        ancestry.lbl_guidance.Caption = guidance
'            End If
'
'        End If
'    Next c
End Sub

Thanks so much for helping me out with this!

Maybe c.Parent.lbl_guidance.Caption = guidance or something like that.  Or in addition to the textbox c also pass a reference to Me from the active userform instance.  I can look at this tomorrow maybe.

@Tim Williams I found the solution and updated the response

While we managed the code to work, we still do not know why it worked running the form with F5 but not when loading the form from a macro or sub, though, is that right?

I don't have time to test things out today, but the answer is in here for sure: https://rubberduckvba.blog/2017/10/25/userform1-show/
